# How do I find the location of an integer in an array of arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Given:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [1,2,3,7],
     [1,2,3,4]]
```

What do I need to do to output the location of the 7 as (1,3)?

I've tried using .index to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'matrix'

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 7],
     [1, 2, 3, 4]]

Matrix[*a].index(7)

=> [1, 3]
```

Comment: I tried that and I receive an error in my terminal saying "cannot load such file -- Matrix" plus some other stuff -- do I need to install a gem for matrix to work on my computer?

Comment: I edited my answer, use lowercase `require 'matrix'` instead of `require 'Matrix'`

Comment: To obtain the locations of all (say) `3`'s: `Matrix[*a].each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,row,col),arr| arr << [row,col] if e==3 } #=> [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your sub-arrays are all the same width, you can flatten it into a single array and think of the position as `row_num * row_width + col_num`:

```
idx = a.flatten.index(7)
row_width = a[0].length
row = idx / row_width
col = idx - (row * row_width)
puts [row, col] # => [1, 3]
```

Or you could just iterate it to find all matches:

```
def find_indices_for(array, value)
  array.with_object([]).with_index do |(row, matches), row_index|
    matches << [row_index, row.index(value)] if row.index(value)
  end
end

find_indices_for(a, 7) # => [[1, 3]]
find_indices_for(a, 2) # => [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: `p idx.divmod(a[0].size) => [1,3]`

Comment: Oh, nice, I wasn't aware of divmod.

Comment: Chris, you'll now be using it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`each_with_index` works pretty well here:

```
def locator(array, number)
  locations = Array.new
  array.each_with_index do |mini_array, index|
    mini_array.each_with_index do |element, sub_index|
      locations << [index, sub_index] if element == number
    end
  end
  locations
end
```

Now, `locator(array, number)` will return an array of containing all the locations of `number` in `array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def locs2D(a,e)
  a.size.times.with_object([]) do |row,arr|
    row.size.times { |col| arr << [row,col] if a[row][col] == e }
  end
end

locs2D(a,7) #=> [[1, 3]] 
locs2D(a,3) #=> [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```